# vue-bootstrap shows components content badly when page loads

Tags: javascript, vue.js, webpack, bootstrap-vue

I use [vue bootstrap](https://bootstrap-vue.org/) framework in my project. When page loading the components content show up on page for 1 seconds then page loading finishes everything seem normal for example modal window or dropdown. You can view from picture what I want to mean. So I don't know why this happens. And I use webpack to compile scss and js and inside head section I call these css and js files.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Use an isLoading variable , set it as false initially and change it to true once the dom is loaded

Comment: You mean something like when dom loads show some fixed element which describes page is loading but I don't want to do it